# Auto width and height for SVG image

Tags: image, svg, d3.js

I am new to `SVG`, so sorry if this is a bit of a noob question. I am trying to figure out how to get an image to display with the full width and height of the referenced image. I am using `D3.js` to build a graph and I want a logo to appear in the corner. The problem is that the image `href` will be set using javascript, so the image being referenced is never a fixed width or height. What I am wanting is the image to display in it's full width and height, not scaled up or down. What I was hoping for is the ability to automatically set the width and height of the image based on it's content, such as setting the `width` and `height` attributes to `auto`. This however just results in the image not being shown.

```
d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr('id','mySVG')
  .attr({
      "width": "100%",
      "height": "100%"
  })
  .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height )
  .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "none");

d3.select('#mySVG')
  .append('image')
  .attr('image-rendering','optimizeQuality')
  .attr('height','auto')     <--- This does not work
  .attr('width','auto')      <--- This does not work
  .attr('xlink:href', logoUrl)
  .attr('x','0')
  .attr('y','0');
```

How would I go about specifying that the SVG image `width` and `height` must be dynamically determined based on the referenced image size?

Comment: Is there any reason why you aren't just using an img tag?

Comment: Hi Wex. You mean an `html` `img` tag? I would prefer to keep the solution in `SVG` if possible. Would like the image embedded in the `SVG` for the graph that is being constructed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Doesn't SVG support auto width and height for images?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080273/doesnt-svg-support-auto-width-and-height-for-images)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I don't think 'auto' is a valid value for the 'length' attr of a svg image element. Take a look at the spec [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#DataTypeLength).  You might want to use '100%'

You *could* load the image then inspect the width and height onload.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WQBPC/4/

```
var logoUrl = 'http://placehold.it/100x50&text=Logo';

//SVG Setup stuff
var svg =  d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr('id','mySVG')
  .attr({
      "width": '100%',
      "height": '100%'
  })

var svg_img=  svg.append('image')
  .attr('image-rendering','optimizeQuality')
  .attr('x','0')
  .attr('y','0');

//Load image and get size.
var img = new Image();
img.src = logoUrl;
img.onload = function() {
 var width = this.width;
 var height = this.height;

 svg_img .attr('height', height)
  .attr('width',width)
  .attr('xlink:href', logoUrl)

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
d3.select("svg")
  .append("image")
    .attr("id", "myImage")
    .attr("xlink:href", "myImage.png")
    .on("load", function(d) { 
        var myImage = new Image();
        myImage.onload = function() {
            d3.select("#myImage")
                .attr("width", this.width)
                .attr("height", this.height);
        }
        myImage.src = "myImage.png";
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a couple years since this has been asked but I'm currently trying to determine some things about the use of `auto` as a value for width or height myself and thought I would share what I've found. According to [Amelia Bellamy-Royds' 2015 article](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/)  on scaling SVGs and the [codepen example](https://codepen.io/AmeliaBR/pen/ZYBmOG) she provides, if you put `auto` in as either the `width` or the `height` value of your `<svg>`, along with a value for the `viewBox`, you should be able to see the content scaling proportionately. Unfortunately, she also points out that at the time this only worked in "Blink/Firefox" browsers. [Blink is a fork of part of WebKit](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/J41PSKuMan0/gD5xcqicqP8J), so it's possible that by now Chrome will support this as well. I am seeing behavior in Chrome which would seem to support this possibility, but I'm also getting an error so YMMV.