# How to get the width and height of an image? ( getBBox() size of SVG return 0 )

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to get the width and height of image. I try to use **getBBox()**, but it just return 0 and 0, which can't return 40 and 40.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.3/d3.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="viewImg"></div>
    <script>
      var w = 200;
      var h = 200;

      var svg = d3.select('#viewImg')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width',w )
      .attr('height',h )
      .style('border', '1px solid #000');

      svg.append('svg:image')
        .attr('xlink:href', 'https://en.js.cx/clipart/ball.svg')
        .attr('x', 20)
        .attr('y', 20)
        .attr('id','plz');

      console.log(plz.getBBox());

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

What can I do to correct it ? Thanks! .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images with `height` or `width` of zero or unset are not getting rendered:
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_Image_Tag

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.3/d3.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="viewImg"></div>
    <script>
      var w = 200;
      var h = 200;

      var svg = d3.select('#viewImg')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width',w )
      .attr('height',h )
      .style('border', '1px solid #000');

      svg.append('svg:image')
        .attr('xlink:href', 'https://en.js.cx/clipart/ball.svg')
        .attr('x', 20)
        .attr('y', 20)
        .attr('height', 20)
        .attr('width', 20)
        .attr('id','plz');

      console.log(plz.getBBox());

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

So set `height` and `width` and it will work properly.

Answer (score 1):

When you first run it, the browser hasn't loaded the image yet and reports image dimensions as 0. If you reload the page, the image is cached and Chrome (at least) reports on the correct image dimensions. If you know what your image dimensions are going to be, @Ruedi.Angehrn's answer will do the trick. If you need to use different images or don't know in advance what your image dimensions are going to be, you will need to use a different technique, for example by waiting for the page content to load fully before running getBBox().

Comment: I doubt that waiting helps. SVG-Images without `height` nor `width` attributes or with values of zero are not getting rendered (also see @Ruedi.Angehrn link). So waiting for something that does not get rendered could take a while.

Comment: @Lain good point. Only Chrome is rendering the image without the HTML/SVG attributes for width and height, and setting CSS width and height to "auto" or "100%" doesn't solve it.

Comment: Seems this has already been asked and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989680/auto-width-and-height-for-svg-image